# Prove the function

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Prove

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: n\ge 1 \rightarrow 2^n\le 2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1.$

I did that $2^n \le\ 2^{n+2} - 2^{n}$ and then $2^n < 2^{n+2} - 2^{n-1}$

but have no idea how to add $-1$ in the function and let the $2^n \le\ 2^{n+2} - 2^{n} - 1$

Comment: Huh? In what world?

Comment: I can't type apparently, $2^n=2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$ and $2^{n-1}\geq 1$. @mathguy

Comment: If n=1 then 1=$2^{n-1} $.  If n>1 then $1 < 2^{n-1} $

Answer (score 4):

Use a geometric series to show that $1+2+\cdots +2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$.

Here is an **alternative approach**:

Write the equation as $2^{n+1} \ge 2^n + 2^{n-1} +1$.

For $n=1$ it is easy to check that $4 \ge 2 + 1 +1$.

Suppose the statement is true for $n$ and multiply across by $2$ to get
$2^{n+2} \ge 2^{n+1} + 2^{n} +2 \ge 2^{n+1} + 2^{n} +1$,
hence the statement is true for $n+1$.

A moment's reflection will show the connection between this approach and
my first approach above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just prove that

$$x\le 2x-\frac x2-1$$
for $x\ge2$. Also an alternative is a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Express everything except the $-1$ in terms of $2^{n-1}$, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1=2^{n-1}*(4-1)-1=2^{n-1}*3 -1 \ge 2^{n-1}*3-2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}*2=2^n $